# Separated seminormed space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(F, \langle \cdot\;,\;\cdot\rangle)$ be a complex Hilbert space.  Let $M$ a positive semidefine operator on $F$.

Clearly $(F,\|\cdot\|_M)$ is a seminormed space, where
$$\|x\|_M=\langle Mx\;,\;x\rangle^{1/2},$$
for all $x\in F$.

Clearly $(F,\|\cdot\|_M)$ is a normed space iff $M$ is injective.

> Assume that $M$ is not injective, is $(F,\|\cdot\|_M)$ a separated space? My goal is to see if the limit of a given convergent sequence in $(F,\|\cdot\|_M)$ is unique or not.

Comment: A semi-normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is separated (=Hausdorff) if and only if $\|\cdot\|$ is a (true) norm.

Comment: In my case this is equivalent to $M$ is injective?

Comment: Yes indeed. Or equivalently $Mx=0$ implies $x=0$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you. Clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Mx =0$ with $x \neq 0$ then $\{x,x,x...\}$ converges to both $x$ and $0$.

[If $x_n=x$ for all $n$ then  $\|x_n-x\|=\|0\|=0$ so $x_n \to x$. Also, $\|x_n -0\|=\langle Mx , x \rangle =0$ since $Mx=0$. Hence $x_n \to 0$ also].

Comment: Please I don't understand your example

Comment: It is the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n=x$ for all $x$. @Schüler

Comment: How this sequence converges to 0?

Comment: @Schüler See the explanation I have added to my answer.